# SQL duplicate rows with multiple left joins

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, left-join

I'm currently facing the following problem:
  I have 3 tables I need information from and both of these joins are one to many. For some reason second join creates duplicates of rows and as a result second return value gets messed up (bb.count gets multiplied by the amount of second join rows)

```
SELECT aa.id, sum(bb.count), count(DISTINCT cc.id)
FROM aaaa aa
LEFT JOIN bbbb bb ON bb.aa_id = aa.id
LEFT JOIN cccc cc ON cc.bb_id = bb.id
GROUP BY aa.id
```

Is there a way to get the proper sum of bb.count without another query?
The moment I remove second left join everything's fine, unfortunately I need it for the third return value and I can't group them without resulting in a duplicate (sort of) rows in result.

Lets say there's

```
bb1.count = 9
bb2.count = 5
```

And there's 2 rows where `cc.bb_id = bb1.id`
The result I get is 23 instead of 14.

Comment: a minimal working sample?..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're experiencing aggregate fanout in the above query.

This happens because there is

- either a 1-1 or 1-N join between `aaa` & `bbb`
- there is a 1-N join between `bbb` & `ccc`

The latter join creates `M` duplicates for rows that exist in `bbb` if they are joined to M rows via the join to `ccc`

To fix the error, split the query up into two CTEs & join the result.

```
WITH agg_bb AS (
SELECT aa.id, sum(bb.count)
FROM aaaa aa
LEFT JOIN bbbb bb ON bb.aa_id = aa.id
GROUP BY aa.id
)
, agg_cc AS (SELECT aa.id, count(DISTINCT cc.id)
FROM aaaa aa
LEFT JOIN bbbb bb ON bb.aa_id = aa.id
LEFT JOIN cccc cc ON cc.bb_id = bb.id
GROUP BY aa.id
)
SELECT * FROM agg_bb JOIN agg_cc USING (id)
```

In general, to avoid fan outs, only apply aggregate operations to the columns from the rightmost relation in a series of joins. If you find you're aggregating columns from the middle tables, split the query up as I have done above. Only the following functions are invariant across a fan out: `COUNT DISTINCT`, `MIN`, `MAX`