# Redshift Query returning too many rows in aggregate join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I am sure I must be missing something obvious. I am trying to line up two tables with different measurement data for analysis, and my counts are coming back enormously high when I join the two tables together.

Here are the correct counts from my **table1**

```
select line_item_id,sum(is_imp) as imps 
from table1 
where line_item_id=5993252 
group by 1;
```

[image]

Here are the correct counts from **table2**

```
select cs_line_item_id,sum(grossImpressions) as cs_imps
from table2 
where cs_line_item_id=5993252 
group by 1;
```

[image]

When I join the tables together, my counts become inaccurate:

```
select a.line_item_id,sum(a.is_imp) as imps,sum(c.grossImpressions) as cs_imps
from table1 a join table2 c
ON a.line_item_id=c.cs_line_item_id
where a.line_item_id=5993252
group by 1;
```

[image]

I'm using aggregates, group by, filtering, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is the schema for these tables:
[image]

Comment: looks like you are running into a cartesian join - lineitemid must not be unique in both tables

Comment: line_item_id is not unique in either table. Each row in both tables corresponds to a single measurement count, either is_imp = 1 or is_imp = 0 in the case of table 1. Any idea how to work around?

Comment: either join on the primary key of both tables or roll up first and then join

Comment: you're experiencing query fanout, see this other answer explaining this phenomenon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279081/sql-duplicate-rows-with-multiple-left-joins/46280040#46280040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.imps table2_imps from
(select line_item_id,sum(is_imp) as imps 
from table1  
group by 1)a
join 
(select line_item_id,sum(is_imp) as imps 
from table1  
group by 1)b
on a.select line_item_id=b.select line_item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a Cartesian product for each `line_item_id`.  There are two relatively simply ways to solve this, one with a `full join`, the other with `union all`:

```
select line_item_id, sum(imps) as imps, sum(grossImpressions) as cs_imps
from ((select a.line_time_id, sum(is_imp) as imps, 0 as grossImpressions
       from table1 a
       where a.line_item_id = 5993252
       group by a.line_item_id
      ) union all
      (select c.line_time_id, 0 as imps, sum(grossImpressions) as grossImpressions
       from table2 c
       where c.line_item_id = 5993252
       group by c.line_item_id
      )
     ) ac
group by line_item_id;
```

You can remove the `where` clause from the subqueries to get the total for all `line_tiem_id`s.  Note that this works even when one or the other table has no matching rows for a given `line_item_id`.

For performance, you really want to do the filtering *before* the `group by`.